# Birthday problem extension to unequal probabilities and multiple collisions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday-paradox

Let $p_1, ... ,p_k$ denote the probabilities of drawing bin $1, .. ,k$, where $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} p_i= 1$. My question is if we draw $n$ times, how can I show that the probability of no bin being drawn $C$ or more is maximized by $p_1 = p_2 = ... = p_k = 1/k$ ?

Comment: One way: show that the chance does not decrease when you replace both $p_1$ and $p_2$ by $(p_1+p_2)/2.$  The result easily follows from this.